# Can not get metadata when using reflect-metadata and decorators

Tags: typescript, annotations, ecmascript-5

Here is a gist containing my code:

```
import "reflect-metadata";

let metadata_key = Symbol("order");

function GetOrder(target: MyOrder, key: string, value: any) {
  return {
    value : function (...args: any[]) {
      let metadata = Reflect.getMetadata(metadata_key, target, "order");
      console.log("Printing out metadata.....");
      console.log(metadata);
      return value.value.apply(this, args);
    }
  };
}

class MyOrder {

  @Reflect.metadata(metadata_key, false)
  private order : boolean;

  @GetOrder
  public checkMetadata() {
    console.log("Tried to get metadata with decorator");
  }

}
```

https://gist.github.com/brittcagnina/3f048ce61aca06bd041c8fa67c7e2199

I am trying to get the metadata property "false", which was set on the class member "order", but new GetOrder().checkMetadata() doesn't print "false" it out to the console.

All tips and help welcome!

Comment: What is this `JsonQuery`?

Comment: Should have been "MyOrder", I've change the example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't work for you, but this works:

```
function GetOrder(target: MyOrder, key: string, descriptor: any) {
    console.log(target, key, descriptor);

    const newDescriptor = Object.assign({}, descriptor);

    newDescriptor.value = function() {
        let metadata = Reflect.getMetadata(metadata_key, target, "order");
        console.log("metadata value is: ", metadata);
        return descriptor.value.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    console.log(newDescriptor);

    return newDescriptor;
}
```

Comment: But it seems like it isn't working.  It I set @Reflect.metadata(metadata_key, true), then I am still getting "metadata value is:  false".  Can you confirm this?

Comment: No. For me it works when setting it to `true` as well